# Spinner methods (setSelection) not working for only one spinner in activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my activity, I have two spinners. I have to set their selections based on certain values.

One of the spinners (`gradeSpinner`) works fine. But the other, `boardSpinner`, doesn't. None of its methods work, and I need `setSelection` to work properly.

Java code: https://gist.github.com/shlokj/1254c3caeaf1e36786b6128462304cfe

Layout file: https://gist.github.com/shlokj/d0bacad8786b1449a6fbb680f005211b

Why doesn't one spinner work, while the other does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your setSelection before setting adapter.

After seeing your code you forgot to put the second parameter of `setSelection()`.

It accepts two selection `setSelection(position in int, Boolean)`

E.g.

```
setSelection(boardNumber - 7, true)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I hadn't provided the second argument,